Fetch() Javascript method PUT not working. Error: 404
I have a problem, I make my Discord bot but the Put method doesn't work. It gives me an error. At the same time if I make a regular json file without attachment it works fine. What is my mistake? This problem has been plaguing me for three days.
This code is working:
JSON:
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "How to Use Fetch to Make GET Requests in React",
  "content": "In this blog post, we will learn how to use the Fetch API to make GET requests in React...",
  "author": "David",
  "date": "2023-01-01"
}

JavaScript:
const data = {
  title: "How to Use Fetch to Make PUT Requests in React",
  content: "In this blog post, we will learn how to use the Fetch API to make PUT requests in React..."
};

const requestOptions = {
  method: "PUT", // Specify the request method
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, // Specify the content type
  body: JSON.stringify(data) // Send the data in JSON format
};

// Make the request
fetch("http://localhost:3000/economy", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json()) // Parse the response as JSON
  .then(data => console.log(data)) // Do something with the data
  .catch(error => console.error(error)); // Handle errors

I tried making attachments as well as sending changes:
fetch("http://localhost:3000/economy")
.then(economy => economy.json())
.then(test1 => {

  let gettur = test1[0].op[0].server


  let edit = (test1[0].op[0].server = "Bubalo");

  console.log(edit);


  const respond = fetch("http://localhost:3000/economy", {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(edit),
  })
.then (response=>console.log(response))

  console.log(gettur);
});

JSON:
{
  "economy": [
    {
      "op": [
        {
          "server": "1089497578141388920",
          "users": [
            {
              "id": "950379710284718111",
              "cash": 200,
              "bank": 300
            },
            {
              "id": "768486511531393024",
              "cash": 0,
              "bank": 2000
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "server": "1089497578141388720",
          "users": [
            {
              "id": "950379710284718111",
              "cash": 200,
              "bank": 300
            },
            {
              "id": "768486511531393024",
              "cash": 0,
              "bank": 2000
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "id": "5b91"
    }
  ]
}

Error 404:


by the way ... body: JSON.stringify() would result in an undefined body - as for the error, who knows, perhaps your server code sends a 404 if the body of a PUT to that endpoint is undefined - i.e. knowing the server code is important

how are you?

I see you missed an argument in the body line, perhaps the app running on your localhost doesn't allow body to be undefined.

    const respond = fetch("http://localhost:3000/economy", {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(xxx), // <- Right here
      });


Besides, If the former doesn't solve this. I don't consider a 404 error could be caused due to missing data (400 Bad Requests are made for thar). Would you mind sending us the "/ PUT" Controller of your backend?

Hope you find a solution out of that :).

Hello, i use Json-Server. Downloaded from:
linkHere
if i write     body: JSON.stringify(edit),
that return 404

Oh, perhaps now I see the problem, don't you have to specify an id at the end of your PUT url? for example: http://localhost:3000/economy/1. This to clarify which  JSON entity will be modified.

I maked this
 
   const respond = fetch("http://localhost:3000/economy/1", {
  method: "PUT",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(edit),
   })
 .then (response=>console.log(response))
 
   console.log(gettur);
 });

But i have error -3008  code enotound hostname: discord.com
I think localhost:3000/economy/1  is undefined
